# Drawing a sin function in c

Tags: c, math, trigonometry

I'm trying to draw (using ASCII text characters) a sin function in C with the "y" component as the amplitude, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

I got this far : https://i.stack.imgur.com/eARM5.jpg

Then I thought about trying to use the sin function some how so I wrote `y = x * sin();`

But I keep getting an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmfQt.jpg

The output should be something like this:

```
***
*****
***
```

Comment: I'd start by telling sin() what angle you want the sinus of, and I'd also be a bit more careful mixing integers and doubles.  Also x is never initialized, and you trash the value you calculate in y.  Fix that, see what happens and come back with other specific problems you might have.

Comment: Please put your code in your question.  Don't ask people to use external sites.

Comment: You kind of just told us what you're doing and that it didn't work - there isn't actually a question here.  You should ask something specific.

Comment: @ma21212 That's exactly what I explain in my comment!!!

Comment: well I want it to do it from 0 to 2pi

Comment: Also, if this is homework, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define RESOLUTION 20
#define AMPLITUDE  80
#define ZxPI 6.283

int main()
{
    int i;

    for( i=1; i<=RESOLUTION; i++ )
    {
        float x = (AMPLITUDE/2) * (sin( (ZxPI / RESOLUTION)*i ) + 1);
        int y = x ;
        while( y-- )
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```